# Ionic routing with tabs and side menu

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to build an app that uses both tab interface and side menu for going to states.

Now what I want is that side menu linked views also have original tabs under their selected tabs, once on those new views.

**router.js**

```
function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider

.state('app', {
  url: "/app",
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: "js/base/menu.html"
})

.state('app.tabs', {
  url: '/tabs',
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: 'js/base/tabs.html',
      controller: 'TabsController as tabsController'
    }
  }
})

.state('app.tabs.old', {
  url: '/old',
  views: {
    'old': {
      templateUrl: 'js/old/old.html',
    }
  }
})

.state('app.tabs.new', {
  url: '/new',
  views: {
    'new': {
      templateUrl: 'js/new/new.html',
    }
  }
})

.state('app.tabs.profile', {
  url: '/profile',
  views: {
    'profile': {
      templateUrl: 'js/profile/profile.html'
    }
  }
});
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/tabs');}
```

Here **old** and **new** are in tabs, while **profile** should be accessed from side menu, and also have old and new tabs on bottom on its view.

**menu.html**

```
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="header-style">
      
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
      
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="right">
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <!--THE MOST IMPORTANT PART-->
        <ion-item nav-clear class="item item-avatar" href="#/profile">
          <img src="../images/img/avatar/header-avatar-2.png">
          <h2 class="item-text-center">{{user}}'s Profile</h2>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

Now the most important is in ion-item, I tried everything, from

- *href*
- *onclick*
- *ng-click* to go to state
- *ui-sref*

  and obviously did not do it right.

Any suggestions how to connect the profile view to the app?

Comment: check this codepen .this might help you http://codepen.io/calendee/pen/JdtuG

Comment: tnx..I ran upon the same codepen, and am trying to model something similar